# When, exactly, does Scala code perform heap allocations?

Tags: scala

I've written a lot of high-performance Java code, and past experience has taught me that one of the most important things for getting peak performance is to be fully aware of the load you're putting on the garbage collector, and work to reduce that load in critical loops.  For example, cryptographic hash functions should be written in such a way that they never allocate any memory.

Prior to Java 1.5 it was very easy to know exactly when Java code would be compiled into JVM bytecodes that performed heap allocation: only the "new" keyword in Java source code would result in a heap allocation.  Post-Java-1.5 you can just look at the "desugaring" of the new language features (like int->Integer autoconversion).

I'm having a really, really, really hard time finding an equivalent answer for Scala, and this is a problem.  Did I miss it?  Where can I find a clear, comprehensive explanation of exactly when the Scala compiler will produce heap-allocating bytecodes?  And no, the scala compiler source code isn't an answer since it changes over time -- I'm asking about the language rather than one specific compiler.

Edit: forgot to mention that the Java primitive "+" applied to Strings is a language-level construct that incurs heap allocation.  So pre-Java-1.5 it should be "new and +-on-String".

Comment: Rex Kerr does number crunching and is involved in efficiency profiling, including library code. Maybe his SO answers would be enlightening, if they're searchable. My small contribution below was delayed by making dinner in time to watch Wonder Woman.  Usual keywords would work `http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A247533+boxed+primitives` since almost every Rex Kerr answer is serious and useful.

Comment: Thanks som-snytt.  I'm aware of boxed primitives, and the answer to the question "when does scala use boxed primitives" would definitely be part of the answer to my question, but a long way from the full answer.  For example, scala's lambda expressions aren't primitives in this sense but they are a language construct that requires heap allocations (at least in the general case)...

Comment: … maybe I should have asked if Scala's heap allocation behavior is predictable and well-defined, which I think is what I really want to know, but asking it that way risks inciting a language-flame-war.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend getting to know the program JD-GUI, which decompiles .class files into java-ish code and lets you inspect it. I've learned a lot about how Scala code is compiled from looking at that.

http://jd.benow.ca/

Comment: I think maybe you've misunderstood the question...  I already know how to figure out if a specific program produces heap-allocating bytecodes.  I seek to know the general rule so that I don't have to decompile every single Scala program I write.  If I had to do that, I wouldn't write many :)

Comment: Sure. I was saying that the best way was to build up the mapping yourself. Most things have a relatively straightforward interpretation, but it is obviously much more complex than Java's.

Comment: I should amend that to say that anything that involves the specialized  annotation is about as straightforward as reading an Aramaic translation of Infinite Jest.